# P-I-V laser diode characterization: Integrated sphere or not?

Tags: optics, laser, electronics

I read that to do a P-I-V laser diode characterization there are two ways:

-Coupling the laser to the Detector through an Integrating Sphere. 
Setup would be: laser diode-integrated sphere-photodetector-power meter

-Direct Coupling Method:
Setup would be: laser diode-photodetector-power meter

Which one is the best to do accurate measurements?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the total power out of the laser, regardless of changes in beam divergence, then use the integrating sphere.

If you want to measure the power into a certain region of solid angle in front of the laser, use the direct coupling  method.

If the laser divergence is not large, and doesn't change much (for example due to the laser self-heating) over the range of operating conditions you test, and the detector is large enough, then you will see essentially the same results for both methods.

Comment: Indeed, I want the total power out of laser and also I need to do beam divergence measurements. What would you suggest? Still the direct coupling method?

As far as I understood, if I use the integrating sphere, then I have to do another setup to measure the beam divergence. Is it right?

Comment: @Ida, yes. AFAIK, you normally use a camera-based setup to do beam divergence.